# Значение слов "проверка", "проверять"

Tags: значение-слов

Каково значение слов "проверка", "проверять"?

Comment: См. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Answer (score 1):

Значение слов можно посмотреть в любом толковом словаре или например на сайте Грамота (см:  http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/)